# Select only children of a div but not grandchildren using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to select only children of a div using CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Child
    <div>GrandChild</div>
  </div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper div:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/781vcf4L/3/

The above CSS applies the CSS property only to a grandchild. I removed the `:first-child` part and it applies the property to all divs (children and grandchild).

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="display: inline-block">Child
    <div>GrandChild</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block">Child</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block">Child</div>
</div>
```

**How can I apply the CSS property to children only?**

Comment: ahhhhh it worked! It was driving me insane...

Answer (score 4):

A space between two selectors is the [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators) which, unsurprisingly, selects all descendants including children and grandchildren.

Replace it with the [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#child-combinators) (`>`) which selects only children.

Comment: Great! It worked. Thank you for lesson. I will have a read on those :) Thank you once more!